# Namespace not recognizing numpy as np

Tags: python, numpy

I have code where I import numpy

```
import numpy as np
import foo as my_foo
```

But in my function defined as follows,

```
   def baz(x):
      np.array(x)
      ...
      return x
```

I get the error >`Variable np referenced before assignment`. I solved it by adding an import inside the function.

However, I am not sure why the import was not recognized. Would I be able to detect conflicts if my foo import has also imported numpy and called it numpy?

Comment: The `...` in `baz` has an assignment like `np = thing` inside, or maybe an import that happens _after_ you call `np.array(x)`.

Comment: The import is before np.array(x). No np = thing either.

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they are in the same file. Otherwise it should work.

Comment: They are in the same file.